# While loops within while loops and output php?

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop

I have a while loop to show the replies for a post on my website.

The value for parentID used in the query is $post['postID'] which is an array of details for the post being viewed.

As seen below it outputs the following (each subject is a link to view the full post)

```
$q = $dbc -> prepare("SELECT * FROM boardposts WHERE parentID = ?");
$q -> execute(array($post['postID']));
while ($postReply = $q -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
     echo '<p><a href="http://www.example.com/boards?topic=' . $_GET['topic'] . '&amp;view=' . $postReply['postID'] . '">' . $postReply['subject'] . '</a>';
}
```

This currently outputs something along the lines of,

**Replies To This Message:


subject 1

subject 2

subject 3

subject 4**

Is there a way in which I can also in the list include replies to the replies, something along the lines of,

**Replies To This Message:


subject 1

         subject 1 reply

         subject 1 reply

                 subject 1 reply reply

subject 2

subject 3

         subject 3 reply

         subject 3 reply

                 subject 3 reply reply

subject 4

         subject 4 reply

subject 5

subject 6

         subject 6 reply

                 subject 4 reply reply**

I understand all the indenting can be with css, but am stuck as to how to pull the data from the mysql database and in the correct order, I tried while loops within while loops, but that involved queries inside while loops, which is bad!

Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 2):

I suspect what you're going to have to do is redesign your database to store the thread/subject relationship in a field so that you can pull all the threads in one query and then sort them programmatically in php.  If you have a parent_id field and each reply row knows who its parent is and what its order is (presumably the order is simply id > previous id) it's pretty simple to then organize them as you need them.

You can then walk your response list and throw all the items into JSON(y) Object that has all your nested responses in their correct order/relationship.

To reduce unwanted bloat, you may want to store the top level parent ID as well, so that you can easily pull only those threads that belong to specific top level threads. That way you can easily grab only the threads that belong to, for instance, the last 20 top level threads (so as to reduce unnecessary computing on ancient threads that no one needs, and to build some sort of pagification).

EDIT... some pseudo code...

`select * from row order by top_level_id desc limit 0,20`  // this will give you a max of 20 top level threads, so you're not pulling the entire db. The 0 at the end should be a page variable you pass in from your PHP, so you can do 20,20 for page 2 and 40,20 for page 3

now you do something like this (obviously this is pseudo code, but you should be able to get it done based on this model...

```
$sortedRows; //this will be a JSON object, or hash array

for($row in result){
   addToThreadObj($row);
}

function addToThreadObj($row){
    if( containsParent($row.parent_id))
         addChildToParent($row.parent_id, $row);
    else
         createNewParent($row);
}
```

Comment: Yes I have a parentID for each post, but just don't know where to start going about organizing them

Comment: This approach breaks down for large result sets. (E.g. you basically suck up the entire table every page render) If you need stable, performant hierarchy on top of a SQL database the only real option is the nested set model.

Comment: @Billy ONeal, no, the last paragraph makes it clear how it avoids dealing with the entire DB. Please re-read.

Comment: @Novac, I haven't written a lot of PHP, so, I'm not sure what the syntax would be for doing it, but what you want is to visualize your ITEM object as an XML Node, and the whole tree as an XML DOM (just for comparison's sake).  When you pull a row, you create a Node and then look at your current document and see if there's already a node whose id is this new node's parent ID, if there is, add it as a child to that node, if not, it must be a parent.  Just make sure to loop in the order of your primary key id smallest to largest, since the children will always have a larger id than the parents.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel: That approach falls apart when you try to display a single, large topic. No matter how you slice it, using the adjacency-list model you end up with a tree N levels deep, for which you'll need N database queries (or N joins) in order to enumerate. Your example will work for displaying a simple topics list, but if falls apart under real world use cases.

Comment: Thanks I will try to implement this as best I can

Comment: you just need to step back from your code and think of it in abstract terms... then it'll all fall into place pretty quickly.

Comment: @ Billy ONeal,  In a real world application dialog threads rarely have more than a few hundred replies (even that is somewhat exorbitant).  And if the use-case calls for these sorts of oddly massive threads, then of course you can redesign and yes, clearly there are times when you want to implement a nested set, but for 99% of these sorts of problems, in my experience, a simple parent/child relationship and sort (better yet a client sort!) are totally adequate. In any event... why argue with me? Just post your own answer! :)

Comment: @Billy ONeal, and maybe I'm not understanding you, but I fail to see why you would need more than one query. Yes, you might end up with a huge result set, but that's the result set you'd end up with anyway, since you want to pull all those rows to build your tree.  I would argue a more efficient solution is to not pull the entire tree, but go back to get the sub rows as needed when the user clicks on a given parent row header.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel: A few hundred queries on a busy web app is an unreasonable number of queries. Even for a non busy webapp, if one assumes typical ~1ms delay per query, you've used up half a typical reasonable page loading time just in latency delay between the web and database teirs. If you use adjacency list then you're forced to pull in the entire table, which defeats the point of using a database in the first place.

Comment: @BillyONeal, I think we're talking past each other.  As I've said... one query does the job nicely and pulls only the rows you need for the parent threads. If you believe this pulls too many threads, I fail to see how your example pulls fewer. You're still pulling all the threads associated with the top threads (whether you have a nested set or not).  What "multiple" queries are you referring to? And again, why not just post your nested query answer?